# Close Votes on Story Identification query

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, story-identification

I recently answered [What book has criminals wear a ring?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73146/what-book-has-criminals-wear-a-ring/73150#73150). After answering it, I noticed that the "similar question" area suggested [Looking for a book: possibly entitled "The Ring"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58794/looking-for-a-book-possibly-entitled-the-ring?rq=1), which is indeed the same book. The later question is, in my opinion, significantly superior. Should I put a Close vote in on the older one?

Comment: @Izkata - irony!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of an acceptance of both questions by both OPs, **there's no definitive confirmation that they're the same book.**

I think there's a reasonable case to be made for closing the older one as the duplicate (the newer one is definitely a more detailed and overall better question) but I'd personally vote against it for the reason above.

Comment: That makes sense. For some reason, I had thought that the older answer had been accepted as well.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Since the user on the second question hasn't bothered to log back in since posting their question (although I strongly suspect they've viewed your answer and gone off to find the book), my guess is that it'll remain open forever.

Comment: So, you say that there's no definitive confirmation of story id's being dupes unless both OPs accept answers, but [you just closed a story id as a dupe despite a lack of a matched accepted answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73420/man-wakes-up-most-people-sleepwalk-through-life).

Comment: @phantom42 - I felt it was sufficiently obvious in that case.